# Got a lot of Secure Connection failed errs recently, anyone with similiar experience?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ssl

I'm experiencing a lot of Secure Connection Failures using TBB in China recently. The browser has problem loading all plain network webpages, here's the message displayed in the browser window:

[image]

I tried to refresh the page, use new identity, use various of bridge mode(obfs4, meek,etc), even chaining my TBB after a working VPN(psiphon\Free browser, etc), non of these measures work. The problem is so bad that no pages can be loaded. What should I do now?

Comment: Same problems here, but with a direct connection. (Last 2 days)
I tried to reinstall TOR 7.5, installed 8.0a and same error. When I tried to use a TOR as socks5, other browsers do not work with SSL connections on different ports also. HTTP (80/8080 ports) are working. When I installed TOR browser on a fresh win7 virtual machine - its working... P.S. I didnt install anything on my PC before. Yesterday night it worked, today morning it doesnt... What should I check? Ports are opened, hosts file is clean... Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the iuput, I have no experience with the whole virtual machine stuff, but what you are describing looks like a massive SSL\certificate hiccup. I'm rolling back to previous working version of TBB to see if that change anything. I'll post results when I'm done.

Comment: Negative, it seems that the previous version 7.0.5 is beginning to show the same problem... might be a GFW attack or a massive software bug. By the way, Igor, can you share your experience on using this TBB on virtual machine? I want to try to narrow down the problem, thanks!

Comment: Do your Tor logs show any kind of issues? Also have you checked that the time, date and timezone on the computer is correct?

Comment: The log appears fine during the bootstrap process. The OS automatically synchronize time upon start-up, so I don't think it is an issue. By the way, I kept older version of TBB, they're showing the same symptom at this moment.

Comment: Update: I think I've made a mistake here, onion service sites appears to be unaffected by this bug, I'll edit the original post to avoid confusion.

Comment: This worked for me: https://imgur.com/a/qIiHL I even disabled Kaspersky and it wouldn't work so can't explain it, but finally after 3 days it's working!!